# React.js: How do you change the position of a Component item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you change the position of a Component item in React?

Unless I've misunderstood it, React orders list items by `key`, which is represented in the DOM by `data-reactid`, but I don't know how to modify the `key` of components on the page.

i.e. How do you grab the component, change it's `key`, and then fire a render so that the reordered list renders in the order you've set?

e.g. in the following code example, when the `Click me` link is clicked, the first list item would be swapped with the last list item.

Ideally, this functionality would allow you to dynamically reorder/relocate any component on the page without changing the order of components in the `render` method.

Here is a link to the repo where the full project is located: https://github.com/bengrunfeld/gae-react-flux-todos

```
var TodoBox = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="todo-container">
        <h4>GAE React Flux Todos</h4>
        <TodoList data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var TodoList = React.createClass({
  changePosition: function(e){
    // Change position of list item (e.g. to top/certain position/end of list)
  },
  render:function(){
    var todoNodes = this.props.data.map(function(todo) {
      return (
        <Todo key={todo.id} id={todo.id}>
          {todo.todoText}
        </Todo>
      );
    });
    return (
      <form className="todoList">
        {todoNodes}
        <a onClick={this.changePosition}>Click me</a>
      </form>
    )
  }
});

var Todo = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return (
      <div className="todoItem">
        <input type="text" className={this.props.id} onChange={this.checkInput} defaultValue={this.props.children} ref="todoItem"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `key` prop is not used to order the element, but to reconciliate it between different `render` calls. Elements with the same `key` will not be re-rendered but rather diffed against each other in order to update the DOM optimally. See [Reconciliation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html)

If you want to reorder elements, you need to change their position in your JSX or in the element array you pass as children in your `render` method (`todoNodes`).

In your case, you could make a copy of `this.props.data` in the `TodoList` component state, then update that copy in your `changePosition` method with something like `this.setState({data: reorderedData})`. A good place to make that copy would be in `getInitialState`.

The `render` method of your `TodoList` would then be called again, and you would map over your newly reordered `this.state.data` to create an array of `Todo` elements ordered to your liking.

However, be aware that [props in `getInitialState` is an anti-pattern](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html). Since your data lives in the state of your `TodoBox` component, a way to avoid this would be to have your `TodoList` component call `this.props.onReorder(reorderedData)` in its `changePosition` method. Your `TodoBox` component could then pass an event handler to its `TodoList` child, and update its state with the new data whenever this handler is called.

```jsx
var TodoBox = React.createClass({
  handleReorder: function(reorderedData) {
    this.setState({data: reorderedData});
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="todo-container">
        <h4>GAE React Flux Todos</h4>
        <TodoList data={this.state.data} onReorder={this.handleReorder} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var TodoList = React.createClass({
  changePosition: function(e){
    // Change position of list item (e.g. to top/certain position/end of list)
    // Create a copy of this.props.data and reorder it, then call
    // this.props.onReorder to signal to the parent component that
    // the data has been reordered
    this.props.onReorder(reorderedData);
  },

  render:function() {
    var todoNodes = this.props.data.map(function(todo) {
      return (
        <Todo key={todo.id} id={todo.id}>
          {todo.todoText}
        </Todo>
      );
    });
    return (
      <form className="todoList">
        {todoNodes}
        <a onClick={this.changePosition}>Click me</a>
      </form>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of how React uses keys, and the code example of how to solve the issue.

Comment: JsBin with combination of code from question and this answer, data and sorting added: http://output.jsbin.com/yacacu

Answer (score 0):

Keys are used for something else, not for sorting. React uses `key`s to optimize its internal Virtual DOM operations. It means you tell React that "no matter the order of these siblings, the individual sibling is still identified by this key". That's how React knows whether it should prepend, insert, delete, or append new siblings by reusing the old, without throwing stuff away unnecessarily.

As for your sorting question: To change the order of the siblings, just sort the JavaScript array `this.props.data`.

Comment: props mutation is bad practice

Comment: I actually didn't mean it like that. (I was trying to say get the data from props and sort it.) Thanks for pointing this out.